# how can I get from 2nd activity to 3rd?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my android app, there are 3 activities.  When I click a button on the first screen, it goes to second screen, click a button on the 2nd screen, it should go to the third. However, when I click the button on 2nd screen, it goes to the 1st screen. I don't know what is the problem in my code.

This is the `CatalogueActivity`:

```
package com.Catalogue;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class CatalogueActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.rdb8);
        this.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(CatalogueActivity.this, familyevent.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the `familyevent` activity:

```
package com.Catalogue;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class familyevent extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.familyevent);

        this.button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.r1);
        this.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(familyevent.this, info.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the `info` activity:

```
package com.Catalogue;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class info extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you seeing something in the logcat? some exception? if so can you put that here too.

Comment: Yeah some logcat output would help more

Comment: I understand why our brain rings when there is an error question without a log cat, but in this case there is absolutely *no* need for a log cat, since there isn't any error to begin with (as far as compiler goes, logic is another issue altogether). He has a code logic problem, not an error.

Comment: @facebook: Have you registered the third activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, familyevent.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, info.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

respectivly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

From CatalogueActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), familyevent.class);
startActvity(intent);
```

and from familyevent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), info.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
intent.setClass(this, YourNewActivity.class);
```